# Unable to parse DOM in nodejs with cheerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Using this code, I'm getting no output, just `...` for some reason, and I have no clue why. Edited w/ cheerio attempt

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'):
http.request({
    host: 'www.roblox.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/home',
    method: 'GET',
    agent:false,
}, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var result = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        result += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        var $ = cheerio.load(result);
        console.log($(".rbx-lead").clone().text().trim());
    });
}).end();
```

Comment: What if you try using `cherrio` instead? Does it work?

Comment: I've never tried cherrio; I have no clue how it works

Comment: Well, what's the value of `$`? What does `require('jquery')` return? Why are you passing `window` to it?

Comment: The value of $ is the jQuery object, not the function

Comment: @Sam Here's how to use `cherrio` to find the "You Make the Game" text. http://pastebin.com/GdQaFHfL

Comment: Where did you get the `rbx-lead`? I opened www.roblox.com, viewed its source and I can't find `rbx-lead`.

Comment: It's only visible if logged in (which I am), for testing I tried changing it to something that's visible when not logged in, and I'm having the same issue; so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: To troubleshoot, you can change `console.log($(".rbx-lead").clone().text().trim());` to just `console.log(result);` so you can confirm the HTML that you are getting from the server. (Even better if you use the debugger, but if you don't know how, you can do the `console.log()` change just get it done right away.)

Comment: Of course it's a problem. If it's only visible when you logged in, then you need to somehow find a way to tap into that session and process the data from there. The problem is not with the `cheerio` itself. I just demonstrated how to get a text element from the html and it works.

Comment: I already have a session, as I've said I'm already logged in and I can't load other elements on other pages that don't require a session

Comment: Yes, you're logged in from your browser, but not from your node.js request

Comment: No, I started a session in Node Js.

Comment: Well, from what I can see in your code, you are sending a plain GET request without your logged in session (having both no cookies and no session id).